# Firebase Load Data as Old as X Days

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I'm using Swift 3 and Firebase. I'm trying to load into a feed all the posts from the last X days. What's the way to do this without retrieving all my posts?

I tried doing

```
ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "createdAt").queryStarting(atValue: dateInPast)
```

but it won't let me set a date parameter for .queryStarting(atValue:)

Error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidQueryParameter', reason: 'You can only pass nil, NSString or NSNumber to queryStartingAtValue:'

Data Structure:

```
{
    "createdAt": "20161013134743",
    "imageURL": "",
    "latitude": 44.43127318210377,
    "longitude": 26.07118959027369,
    "objectId": "-KTyI60jaUUuRBj-sIRR",
    "ownerId": "TlQZr5cqSIUboBO8k3bjz3q6oj63",
    "postText": "Bravo sefu' la Moose!",
    "replies": 4,
    "reportCount": 0,
    "score": 5,
    "updatedAt": "20161013134743"
}
```

Comment: Can you show what your data structure looks like (as text please, no screenshots)? Also: what do you mean that it won't let you? Is there an error message?

Comment: Yes, there is an error message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidQueryParameter', reason: 'You can only pass nil, NSString or NSNumber to queryStartingAtValue:'

Comment: Data Structure:
{
  "createdAt" : "20161013134743",
  "imageURL" : "",
  "latitude" : 44.43127318210377,
  "longitude" : 26.07118959027369,
  "objectId" : "-KTyI60jaUUuRBj-sIRR",
  "ownerId" : "TlQZr5cqSIUboBO8k3bjz3q6oj63",
  "postText" : "Bravo sefu' la Moose!",
  "replies" : 4,
  "reportCount" : 0,
  "score" : 5,
  "updatedAt" : "20161013134743"
}

Comment: It looks like `dateInPast` is of an unsupported data type. What is the data type? (note that it's easiest if you edit your question to add that information)

Comment: Thanks for editing. dateInPast is of type Date

Comment: I understand from the error message that Date is not supported as a data type. However, I'd like to know if and how I can achieve something like this with Firebase (loading all posts from the last X days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `createdAt` property is not stored as a date. It is stored as a string: `20161013134743`.

So you'll need to convert your date variable to a similarly formatted string to do the query:

```
let threeDaysAgo = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -3*24*60*60)
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(threeDaysAgo)
ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "createdAt").queryStarting(atValue: dateString)
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't remember why this didn't work when I first tried it, but it does after following your example.